# kdenlive not able to open/save due to apparmor

Tags: ubuntu, apparmor, kdenlive

I've been struggling with this for a few days.

- Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- appamor 2.12-4ubuntu5.1

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/kdenlive-snap-can%27t-save-or-load-because-of-apparmor-4175668980/

My situation is similar with the above link, in that when ever I try to **open a file** in kdenlive nothing happends. The terminal shows me

```
org.kde.solid.udisks2: Failed enumerating UDisks2 objects: "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied" 
 "An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type=\"method_call\", sender=\":1.123\" (uid=1001 pid=4008 comm=\"kdenlive \" label=\"snap.kdenlive.kdenlive (enforce)\") interface=\"org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable\" member=\"Introspect\" error name=\"(unset)\" requested_reply=\"0\" destination=\"org.freedesktop.UDisks2\" (uid=0 pid=1156 comm=\"/usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd \" label=\"unconfined\")"
```

When I run `sudo aa-status` I can see a record for `snap.kdenlive.kdenlive` in Enforce mode

So I tried to `sudo aa-complain snap.kdenlive.kdenlive`  . and it returns

```
Can't find snap.kdenlive.kdenlive in the system path list. If the name of the application
is correct, please run 'which snap.kdenlive.kdenlive' as a user with correct PATH
environment set up in order to find the fully-qualified path and
use the full path as parameter.
```

Next I try to verify if the profile exist in the folder . Looked in `etc/apparmor.d/` folder and cannot find the profile file. There are a few other profiles which is listed in the aa-status, but cannot find in the folder. Those profiles have the same issue to complain/enforce .

When trying to complain/enforce the few profiles that DOES EXIST in `etc/apparmor.d`  it shows correctly `Setting <profile> to complain mode`. This leads me to believe the issue is with the appamor profiles .

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been struggling with the same problem in Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS, snapd v2.48, apparmor 2.10.95 and kdenlive snap v20.04.0. I fixed the symptoms in the following way:

The profile is in `/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.kdenlive.kdenlive`.
Despite the documentation, `aa-easyprof` and `aa-logprof` didn't work converting the denied errors logged in `/var/log/syslog` to a new profile. I also tried invoking complain mode, but couldn't figure it out either. So I iterated through the errors using `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and manually appended lines to the snap profile mentioned above. `aa-notify -s 1 -v` can also be useful.

Here are the lines that removed all my errors (don't forget to put them *inside* the `{}` curly braces). You'll need to run `systemctl reload apparmor` to load the new profile and apparmor will fail to run if there's a problem (`journalctl -xe` is your friend):

```
# fix Open dialog issues (systemctl reload apparmor):

@{PROC}/*/mount{s,info} r,
/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern r,
/etc/fstab r,
/sys/bus/usb/devices/ r,
/usr/bin/localedef ix,
/run/udev/data/* r,
/etc/xdg/** r,
/var/lib/snapd/** r,
/run/user/** r,
/sys/bus/** r,

dbus send
     bus=system
     path="/org/freedesktop/UPower"
     interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable"
     member="Introspect"
     peer=(name="org.freedesktop.UPower"),

dbus send
     bus=system
     path="/org/freedesktop/UPower"
     interface="org.freedesktop.UPower"
     member="EnumerateDevices"
     peer=(name="org.freedesktop.UPower"),

dbus send
     bus=system
     path="/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/**"
     interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable"
     member="Introspect"
     peer=(name="org.freedesktop.UDisks2"),

dbus send
     bus=system
     path="/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/**"
     interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"
     member="{Get,GetAll}"
     peer=(name="org.freedesktop.UDisks2"),

dbus (receive)
    bus=system
    path="/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/**"
    interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"
    member="PropertiesChanged"
    peer=(label=unconfined),
```

(Edit: try this first) I also found this in another Q&A thread, which might explain why these lines haven't been added to the kdenlive snap profile, but it doesn't appear to work either:

```
snap connect kdenlive:removable-media
```

(Edit: see also [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-an-application-installed-as-snap) for talk of removable-media and the `ubuntu-software` permissions settings, still doesn't work)

**HOWEVER**, the Open and Save buttons in kdenlive *still* do not work :-( It's odd because there is a dialog for adding media to the project which works, just no way to open or save a project. Maybe the snap is relying on an external library/snap module to perform these functions?

See also [this link](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=265&t=168910) which appear to suggest kdenlive v21 *should* work, but the [ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekdenlive) doesn't have that version for our ubuntu versions and neither does `snap info kdenlive` :(

Hope this helps someone!

Running from the `/snap/bin/kdenlive` commandline I get the following, which seems quite a common problem with no solutions that I can see:

```
kf5.kio.kio_tags: tag fetch failed: "Failed to open the database"
kf5.kio.kio_tags: "tags:/" list() invalid url
kf5.kio.core: "Could not enter folder tags:/."
```

Appears to be [this bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=416138)

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't fix the problem with the snap, instead I downloaded the portable AppImage from the [kenlive website](https://kdenlive.org/en/download/) which appears to work fine. Make executable with `chmod u+x kdenlive-20.12.0-x86_64.appimage`